# C# index out of range when i run exe from command line and pass arguments to it

Tags: c#, command-line, exe

This is the code that I compile and get its exe:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t1 = args[0];
    var t2 = args[1];
}
```

This is what I wrote in a .bat file:

```
"app.exe" "text\" "text"
```

this is what i write in powershell:

```
>.\run.bat
```

and this is the error:

> some/path/...>"app.exe" "path/to/project" "project"
> Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
> at theApp.Main(String[] args) in path/to/app.cs:line 12

This is weird because the line that I wrote in bat file works perfectly when I write it in powershell directly and press enter but it behave differently when i try to run bat file from another powershell console.

Comment: Open a standard command prompt (cmd.exe, not powershell). Paste in` "app.exe" "some text1" "some text2"` and run it. What happens?

Comment: You're accesing `args` directly without checking first if there are any `args`. In the bat you supply them, hence everything works, but your powershell version has no arguments and errors out because of lack of those parameters.

Comment: @Alejandro `but your powershell version has no arguments` How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @mjwills Because the question states so: `this is what i write in powershell:` and `>.\run.bat `.

Comment: @mjwills same error

Comment: i changed my main to "Console.WriteLine(args[0]);" then i ran the exe from cmd '"DictionaryGenerator.exe" "F:\Programing\C#\ConsoleAppAndDictionary\Dict\" "Dict"' and i got F:\Programing\C#\ConsoleAppAndDictionary\Dict" Dict

Comment: @Alejandro But the powershell is running **the batch file**.

Comment: does it makes any difference if i say i was using powershel inside windows terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my bat file where i wrote this:

```
"app.exe" "a text that ends like this\" "some other text"
```

at the end of first argument there is a \" so i changed it to \\" and now everything works.
It seems like when i write "sometext\" in command line directly it reads it like sometext\, but when i save this command in bat file and try to run this from somewhere else it reads it like the sometext" is my input text so it appent second argument( "othertext" ) to the first one( "sometext\" ) then my c# code only get one argument like this: sometext" othertext.

P.S: When i write command in powershell it doesn't think the \" is an escape sequence but in cmd or when i try to run saved command it think the \" is an escape sequence.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note the first argument in `args` is the program name, the actual arguments start from `args[1]`.
Secondly, which PowerShell version are you running? I tried to re-produce your issue with PowerShell 7 and couldn't, here's my attempt:

1. Inside the VS code .exe folder I created run.bat with the content `"code.exe" "."` in order to start VS code in current folder.
2. I started PowerShell 7 session inside this folder
3. I executed `.\run.bat` just like you did and VS Code opened as expected

No errors as you can see:
[image]

Comment: my powershell version is 5.1.19041.1151. but when i run the '"app.exe" "some text1" "some text2"' in cmd i get the same error.

Comment: in cmd:  
F:\Programing\C#\ConsoleAppAndDictionary\Dict\Generator>"DictionaryGenerator.exe" "F:\Programing\C#\ConsoleAppAndDictionary\Dict\" "Dict"
Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at DictGenerator.DictionaryGeneratorRunner.Main(String[] args) in F:\Programing\C#\DictionaryGenerator\DictionaryGenerator\DictionaryGeneratorRunner.cs:line 12

Comment: Works for me from cmd as well.